# Слово "главное". Его роль и функции в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Я читал, что зачастую оно выступает в качестве вводного. А каким оно еще может быть?

"Главное, напиши ей письмо, да поскорее".

Comment: А каким оно еще может быть? В предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11) Слово главное является вводным в значениях «особенно важно», «особенно существенно»: Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно — запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире; Как крупный учёный, а главное как историк искусства, он пользуется большим авторитетом — в начале обособленного оборота.(http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Главное - верить. Здесь слово "главное" является подлежащим и употреблено как существительное. 
Это моё главное условие. "Главное" - прилагательное, определение.

В Вашем примере "главное" - вводное слово в значении "особенно важно".